# Get full string using awk

Tags: unix

I am unable to get full string using `awk`. For example,
File.txt has,

```
C1 C2 C3
A    B   'A B C'
C    D  'D E F'
```

If I use below code,

```
awk '{print $1 "," $3}' File.txt
```

I am getting output as,

```
A,'A
C,'D
```

Expected output is,

```
A,'A B C'
C,'D E F
```

Comment: Are you sure your file contents is properly formatted / line-broken? for me $1 would be C1 and $3 would be C3?

Comment: Formatting didn't work.

Comment: Please read the formatting help and make it work - you can't expect us to guess what the input would be?

Comment: Formatting seems didn't work. C1,C2,C3 are columns and Rest are values.

Comment: Anyway...awk doesn't know that you want to group words by using the quotes.

Comment: @StefanHegny, OP has not formatted his input file text, expected and actual outputs in this question. But, now I've corrected the question. OP's input text file is delimted with tab characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk '{print $1 "," $3,$4,$5}' file
A,'A B C'
C,'D E F'
```

Comment: I already tried with $3,$4,$5. Any other way like this will no t be feasible for longer string

Answer (score 0):

The default delimeter for `awk` is space. Since your data has tab, you should delimit with '\t'

**file.txt**

```
A    B   'A B C'
C    D   'D E F'
```

**awk command**

```
awk '{BEGIN FS="\t"}{print $1 "," $3}' <file.txt
```

**output**

```
A,'A B C'
C,'D E F'
```